# Empty result in a recursive Java call

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on the following [CodingBat problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p137918):

> Given a string that contains a single pair of parenthesis, compute recursively a new string made of only of the parenthesis and their contents, so "xyz(abc)123" yields "(abc)".
>
> ```
> parenBit("xyz(abc)123") → "(abc)"
> parenBit("x(hello)") → "(hello)"
> parenBit("(xy)1") → "(xy)"
> ```

I attempted to solve it like this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParenBit {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        ParenBit p = new ParenBit();
        p.solve(arg[0], '(', "");
        System.out.println(p.finalResult.toString());
    }

    private List<String> finalResult = new LinkedList<String>();

    private boolean solve(String s, char c, String result) {
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return false;
        char f = s.charAt(0);
        if (f == '(') {
            boolean b = solve(s.substring(1), ')', result);
            if (b) {
                result += f + "";
            }
            if (f == c)
                return true;
        } else if (f == ')') {
            if (c == f) {
                result += f + "";
                finalResult.add(result);
                solve(s.substring(1), '(', "");
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (c == ')') {
                boolean b = solve(s.substring(1), ')', result);
                if (b) {
                    result += f + "";
                }
            } else if (c == '(') {
                return solve(s.substring(1), '(', result);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I called it with this input:

> wow(thesis)

I get empty results. How can I fix this?

Comment: Surely with that rep, you would know not to just to give us a problem and not attempt to debug it yourself. Also, we don't take assignments..

Comment: @AndrewL. it is not assignment, it is a quesiotn online i am trying to learn recursive

Comment: What are your attempts at debugging the program?

Comment: @AndrewL. i ran debag, the condition to check '(' runs but the condition for ')' didn't

Comment: @AndrewL. isn't char a primitive type and == works with them?

Comment: This is a pretty bad use case for recursion in Java. Try implementing fusion sort if you want to learn why it's really useful.

Comment: @CoffeeNinja you mean my solution is bad ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli You should really name your variables better

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli no, the problem is.

Comment: @CoffeeNinja fusion sort? is that a sorting algorithm? a google search yield nothing.

Comment: @Onur sorry, I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort :)

Answer (score 1):

When I paste your code into my IDE, it tells me

```
if (b) {
    result += f + "";
}
```

**The value `f + ""` assigned to '`result`' is never used.**

Meaning you update the `result` parameter but you never use the updated value as a result you always call `solve()` method with an **empty** `result` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has been updated.
Given your rep you should have been able to think it out.

Also if you need to correctly get the result u should not have been using List. Simple String would have done.

A few more input. Rather simply code try to follow the instructions given as well. CodingBat was expecting you to write a method which returns a String not write a program to store output in a variable.

```
private String finalResult = "";

private boolean solve(String s, char c, String result) {
    if (s.length() == 0)
        return false;
    char f = s.charAt(0);
    if (f == '(') {
        result="(";
        boolean b = solve(s.substring(1), ')', result);
        if (b) {
            result += f + "";
        }
        if (f == c)
            return true;
    } else if (f == ')') {
        if (c == f) {
            result += f + "";
            finalResult = result;
            //finalResult.add(result);
            solve(s.substring(1), '(', "");
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (c == ')') {
            result += f + "";
            boolean b = solve(s.substring(1), ')', result);
            /*if (b) {
                result += f + "";
            }*/
        } else if (c == '(') {
            return solve(s.substring(1), '(', result);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean solve(String s, char c, String result) {

  int bpos = s.lastIndexOf(c);
  int epos = s.indexOf(')');

  if ((bpos == -1) || (epos == -1) || (epos < bpos)) {
      return false;
  }

  result = s.substring(bpos,++epos);
  finalResult.add(result);

  return true;
}
```